# Sylius: changing locale back to English not working

Tags: symfony, translation, sylius

I've downloaded the latest version of Sylius through GitHub and added my own Bundle next to it. I changed the locale to NL (Dutch, The Netherlands) and the majority of the site's context changed to Dutch. In addition to the translated Dutch words I saw a lot of translation strings, such as `sylius.frontend.headertext` which I started fixing. In my own Bundle I override from `WebBundle` by return `SyliusWebBundle` in `getParent()`, and in the `Resources/translations` folder I've placed my translation files. Everything worked wonders!

Now I wanted to change back to English to see how the backend looks in this language, but changing the `sylius.locale` to `en` no longer works, not even after clearing the cache or not removing my bundle with custom translations.

Any clues? [SOLVED. see below]

---

**Edit:** When viewing my application in the Production environment it does seem to display English, oddly enough..

**Edit 2:** I cannot answer my own question yet, but I've solved this by going inside my application's Admin Panel > General Settings and there was a language setting I hadn't specifically set. I changed it from `Dutch` to `English` and it solved my problem.

Comment: Btw. if you want to help, please vote for your dutch translations on crowdin, so they get included into sylius. https://crowdin.net/project/sylius/nl

Comment: Hey Paziツ, thanks for your reply. I've made sure the Dutch translation is now at 100% (made 450+ suggestions) and also started voting on existing suggestions.